# How to update database field when an item has been selected from drop down menu in rails?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in ruby on rails, I have a drop down menu bar, I want to select an item from drop down menu bar at that time, database table should to update according to the selected item. 
**_applied_candidate.html.erb** this is my partial page

```
 <p>Current Status: <span class="fontstyle3">
          <% data = CandidateWorkFlow.select(:workflow_step, :next_step).where("step_id = ?", offer_state.current_step) %>            
          <% data.each do | d | %>
            <%= d.workflow_step %>
          <% end %>                    
        </span></p>

        <p>Next Status: <span class="fontstyle3">             
            <% data.each do | d | %>
              <select name="user[role_id]" id="workflow_id">
                <option value="">Please select</option>
                <% d.next_step.split(',').each do | s | %>
                  <% data1 = CandidateWorkFlow.select(:workflow_step).where("step_id = ?",s) %>                   
                   <% data1.each do |l| %>
                      <option value=<% s %> > <%= l.workflow_step %> </option>          
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                </select>
            <% end %>  
        </span>
        </p>
```

`<option value=<% s %> > <%= l.workflow_step %> </option>` this part of code `<%s%>` will store the value of items and this one part of code `<%=l.workflow_step %>` is selectable list, when the item from selectable list has been selected `<%=l.workflow_step%>` then update method should be called.
**AppliedJob.rb** this is my model

```
class AppliedJob < ActiveRecord::Base 
end
```

**applied_jobs** this is my database table 
**| id | user_id | job_posting_id | status | applied_by_id | current_step | prev_step |** these are my field
**JobsController.rb** this is my controller

```
class Candidate::JobsController < Candidate::BaseController
end
```

But in this code above there is no update method

**Is it possible to update database value with the help of model method?** please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using forms and javascript roughly like this:

```
   <% data.each do | d | %>
    <%= form_for url: <your-url> do |f| %>
      <select name="user[role_id]" id="workflow_id">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <% d.next_step.split(',').each do | s | %>
          <% data1 = CandidateWorkFlow.select(:workflow_step).where("step_id = ?",s) %>                   
           <% data1.each do |l| %>
              <option value=<% s %> > <%= l.workflow_step %> </option>          
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </select>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

in your javascript:

```
 $('#workflow_id').change(function(){
   $('#<your-form-id>').submit();
 });
```

Before this you should make your form and select to have corresponding ids (because this is inside a loop same id is repeated for all forms and select input)